# c_str() custom implementation / "=" in the end of every string

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement c_str() function of my custom String class. It seems to work, but for some reason it prints "=" in the end of every string:

```
const char* c_str()
    {       
        char* temp = alloc.allocate(data.size() + 1);
        uninitialized_copy(data.begin(), data.end(), temp);
        temp[data.size()+1] = '\0';
        return temp;
    }
```

Private part of Str class:

```
private:
    Vec<char> data;
    allocator<char> alloc;
```

*Vec is basically vector.

```
int main()
{
    Str s1 = "Hello, beee";
    cout << s1.c_str();
    return 0;
}
```

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
temp[data.size() + 1] = '\0';
```

The `char` array is allocated for `data.size() + 1` bytes, so the indices should be from `0` to `data.size()`. `temp[data.size() + 1]` is just out of the array boundary. This code may also lead to undefined behaviors.

It should be

```
temp[data.size()] = '\0';
```

Comment: Right, I didn't notice that. Thanks

Comment: It's not that it *may* lead to undefined behavior. It *does* lead to undefined behavior. Today, for Trollpidor, the undefined behavior happens to manifest rather benignly as equals signs on the ends of all the strings. Tomorrow it might manifest as nasal demons. That's what it means to be undefined.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the position beyong the border of the array. The index of an array is counted from 0, so the last element's index should be `sizeof(array) - 1`.

`temp[data.size()+1] = '\0';` should be `temp[data.size()] = '\0';`

Comment: Thanks!    I didnt notice that.